# Find Total Primes in Python (Process was terminated Error)

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, numbers, primes

Here is the problem I am solving.

The number 23 is unique in the sense that all of its digits are prime numbers. Furthermore, it's a prime itself. There are 4 such numbers between 10 and 100: 23, 37, 53, 73. Let's call these numbers "total primes".

Complete the function that takes a range `[a, b)` and returns the number of total primes within that range (`a <= primes < b`). The test ranges go up to 10^7.

Examples:
(10, 100)  ==> 4  # [23, 37, 53, 73]
(500, 600) ==> 3  # [523, 557, 577]

I try to solve as this (it returns the correct number for sample tests):

```
def isPrime(n):
  if n < 2: return False
  for x in range(2, int(n**0.5) + 1):
    if n % x == 0:
      return False
  return True

def itsDigits(n):
  for i in set(str(n)):
    if not isPrime(int(i)):
      return False
  return True

def get_total_primes(a, b):
    count=0
    for i in range(a,b):
      if(isPrime(i) and itsDigits(i)):
        count+=1
    return count
```

But Codewars gives me the error:

> Process was terminated. It took longer than 12000ms to complete
>
> Our servers are configured to only allow a certain amount of time for
>   your code to execute. In rare cases the server may be taking on too
>   much work and simply wasn't able to run your code efficiently enough.
>   Most of the time though this issue is caused by inefficient
>   algorithms. If you see this error multiple times you should try to
>   optimize your code further.

Can you please help me optimize my code?

Comment: Simple improvements: Use a faster primality test (there are tons), and store results for things you've already seen. This question is too broad IMHO, though.

Comment: There is no need to generate numbers with non-prime digits

Comment: You need to use some maths and use some data structures. How many times do you check whether 8 is prime, for example? Why? You know the prime digits, `{2, 3, 5, 7}`, why do you loop through all the digits? Once you've checked something is prime, put it in a dictionary or a set to make checking the next time quicker, etc, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, maybe the right way would be to generate only numbers from prime digits first, and then check if these are prime? You can easily generate all possible combinations of *{2, 3, 5, 7}* of a given length using generator expressions, like this:

```
def prime_digit_combinations(length):
    if length <= 0:
        return [0]
    return ((10 ** (length - 1)) * current + rest
            for current in [2, 3, 5, 7]
            for rest in prime_digit_combinations(length - 1))
```

After that you only have to generate all combinations greater than *a* and smaller than *b*, e.g.:

```
def get_possible_total_primes(a, b):
    result = []
    for length in range(len(str(a)), len(str(b)) + 1):
        result.extend(
            num for num in prime_digit_combinations(length)
            if a <= num <= b
        )
    return result
```

and check if these are prime. I bet it will be much faster.